# A function to remove characters from a string

Tags: javascript

I wanted to write a function to remove a set of characters from a string in JavaScript.

I came up with this.

How can it be improved in terms of time/space complexity?

```js
function remove(str, chars) {
    var set = new Set(chars); // looking up presence of char is O(1)
    var arr = [...str]; // operate on an arrray rather than a string to avoid unneccessary string copying
    // What follows is O(N) I think...
    return arr.reduce((p,c) => {
        if(set.has(c)) {
            return p;
        }
        p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []).join('');
}

remove('hello world', 'el') === 'ho word';
```

Comment: Why not use regex?

Comment: A good option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Don't abuse `reduce`. Reduce should be used when you want to *reduce* the list. Take using reduce to find the sum of a list: `[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`.
- Use `filter` if you want to filter a list. `arr.filter(i => !set.has(i))`.
- You may want to instead use [`regex.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). However, it'd require checking your `chars` for any regex escape stuff.

  However if you ignore that, it could be as easy as:

  ```
  function remove(str, chars) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(`[${chars}]`, 'g'), '');
  }
  ```

Otherwise using the above, for \$O(n)\$ time and space complexity, could get you:

```
function remove(str, chars) {
    var set = new Set(chars);
    return [...str].filter(i => !set.has(i)).join('');
}
```

Comment: By the verb *reduce* you mean perform an aggregation function on the collection?

Comment: @Ben Yes that, :) As you should reduce from a `List<T>` to a `T`.